# Borders of integration testing

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing

I want to be specific. So imagine Spring REST backend, which stores data in DB and also communicates to various other services via REST, WS etc.

What actually should be considered integration test?

**MVC**

Using Spring-test, MockMVC we can somehow skip deploy to speed up the testing. It enables to call http request and to test the whole flow. If I will skip it and deploy to application server it should be similar.

**What about remote REST services?**

I guess I can mock beans in test context or I can start some Fake Rest service. Is one off the approaches disqualified from integration testing?

**What about DB?**

It is not easy to mock DB. So often you just start testing(H2) or some real DB directly. Maybe you can mock repositories, but is it integration?

I'm especially interest in connection with Maven's integration-test phase. Also how about the need for deployment of the app(as MockMVC and spring-test are kind of deploy without server), fake servers vs mocking the beans directly.

**Shortly where are the borders of integration testing.** Is it really that opinionated as it seems at first glance?

Comment: It is best explained here https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html

Comment: Nice resource btw. But what does he mean by _trigger a function within your code that reads from the separate service's API_. When testing MVC I can mock all others and do the testing. How to invoke functionality inside the code, does it mean directly calling the service. In this case the deployment to app server is out of scope. Does he intend to do testing external integrations points one by one, by always  mocking other integrations? So there will be no complex test which will check all integrations at once? And how to do it? Create specific spring context for each integration point?

Comment: Its covered as part of point 2 that (start an instance of the separate service (or a test double with the same interface), you can start a mock server that acts as an other service so that you can test the serialization/deserialization that way. End to end test covers all the integrations anyway. He has nicely covered end to end test too in that article

Comment: So is it about the communication check with specific endpoint or about internal application flow and how it will react to various integration points interaction?

Comment: yes exactly!. As you can`t rely on authenticity of the service while testing it is better to mock it out. Anyways you will have end to end test in place to test the  actual flow.

Comment: How do you do it, if you don't have Spring DI, spring-test to the rescue? How do you invoke some remote REST service from within deployed app. I'm questioning if spring-test is the ultimate tool which enables Spring integration testing. Is requestiong controller URL to invoke remote service connector inside the app, violation of integration testing principles?

Comment: why do you think it violates the principles,  if you are thinking of testing remote rest service during integration testing, mock it using MockServer as described in the article. If you want to test including the controller endpoint exposed as part of the app itself then make use of MockMvc (spring-test) to the rescue. if you want to perform tests against deployed app in that case you got to go for acceptance tests (Rest end-to-end) without ui - cucumber is the tool for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181540/discussion-between-zveratko-and-barath).

Comment: sorry I dont have a facility to join chat room from here!